# Label in PopupMenu

Tags: menu

The menu created by this code doesn't show the second label (r1) when it's chosen. How can I fix this?

```
 r1 = SetAccuracy[9.87654321012345678, 18];
 PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], {1 -> 1, r1 -> r1}]
```

Comment: Works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ob8wH.png.  (V10.2, Mac OSX.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the phenomenon is not reproducible.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're asking. Just in case:

```
r1 = SetAccuracy[9.87654321012345678, 18];
{PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], {1 -> 1, r1 -> r1}], Dynamic@x}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's so strange! It was NOT working when I poster the question! Now it works. In another menu, it sometimes stops working correctly without any reason. I don't know what's wrong.